# How to close a tab in vim?

Tags: vim

When I use `:tabnew myfile` in vim it opens a new tab.

When I quit the tab with
`:q` and I move to another tab with `:bn` , the tab is still there.

Can someone explain why and how to really close it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're mixing up tabs and buffers. A tab is simply a way of displaying buffers, closing it doesn't do anything to those.

If you want to delete a buffer from the buffer list, use `:bd`. From the help:

```
:[N]bd[elete][!]            *:bd* *:bdel* *:bdelete* *E516*
:bd[elete][!] [N]
        Unload buffer [N] (default: current buffer) and delete it from
        the buffer list.  If the buffer was changed, this fails,
        unless when [!] is specified, in which case changes are lost.
        The file remains unaffected.  Any windows for this buffer are
        closed.  If buffer [N] is the current buffer, another buffer
        will be displayed instead.  This is the most recent entry in
        the jump list that points into a loaded buffer.
        Actually, the buffer isn't completely deleted, it is removed
        from the buffer list |unlisted-buffer| and option values,
        variables and mappings/abbreviations for the buffer are
        cleared.
```

Comment: What if I have a "tab" that has a several buffers? For example, a tab with two buffers side-by-side in a vertical split. Is there a single command to close all buffers associated with a tab?

Comment: @Jin: `:windo bd` should do what you want.

Comment: It actually closes all tabs that contain that file. In case you want to remove redundant tabs, then 'bd' is most likely not what you want!

Comment: I always use `:bw` (bufferwipeout), but `:bd` may actually be a better, safer way.

Answer (score 65):

You can use `:tabclose` (shortened alias also works `:tabc`).

Read more with `:help tabpage`.

---

As for the buffer coming back with `:bn`, I believe this is normal for "hidden buffers", and `:bn` wraps around to the first buffer when you go past the last one.

See `:help buffer-hidden`

Comment: I think this is the normal behaviour of the bufferlist

Comment: This may not answer the OP's situation directly, but it answers precisely the question posed by their title and is what most coming here will have needed. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you are using common vim: `:bd`

If you are using something like SpaceVim: `SPC+b+d` will delete your current buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`:tabclose` will need to be coupled with `:tabN` instead of `:bn`.  As the original answer suggests tabs and buffers are not the same concept.  If you use tabs using the proper commands will help.